# POST request is working fine in POSTMAN, but not in the expo app, it gets different data

Tags: react-native, api, postman, expo

```
const headerPart = {
    Accept: "*/*",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
};

const sendData = (email, pass) => {
    axios
        .post(
            "https://webapplicationindia.com/demo/study-falcon/Apicontroller/login",
            {
                userId: email,
                userPass: pass,
            },
            { headerPart }
        )
        .then((response) => console.log(response.data.msg));
};

useEffect(() => {
    sendData();
}, []);
```

It works completely fine when I test it from POSTMAN, but shows a complete different result when, it is tested from my expo application. I don't get why the problem is happening.

I am attaching an image:

[image]

Comment: Oops. I think our edits may have collided. I'm not sure what the correct edit is now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

***Here, the main thing is, you need to pass the data as FormData. To do that:***

====>

```
 const formdata = new FormData();
 formdata.append("email", valueForEmail);
 formdata.append("pass", valueForPass);
```

and then, when you send the POST request add it there ==>

```
const response = fetch("YOUR_LINK", {
   method: "POST", 
   body: formdata, 
});
```

---

> Then, you will get the correct response, Thanks in advance.

---